# google map api v3.. tell whether point 1 and 2 are near each other

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i have two google map coordinates...

point 1: "1.326631,103.861297" and 
point 2: "1.326116,103.860873".

Is there any way to do a javascript function to tell whether point 1 & 2 is near to each other probably by through a radius circle? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the calculations, I wrote a function in SQL for calculating radial miles from two points based on latitude and longitude. You could probably use it as a basis for converting it to Javascript if needed.

```
declare @DegToRad as float
declare @Ans as float
declare @Miles as float

set @DegToRad = 57.29577951
set @Ans = 0
set @Miles = 0

set @Ans = SIN(@lat1 / @DegToRad) * SIN(@lat2 / @DegToRad) + COS(@lat1 / @DegToRad ) * COS( @lat2 / @DegToRad ) * COS(ABS(@long2 - @long1 )/@DegToRad)
set @Miles = 3959 * ATAN(SQRT(1 - SQUARE(@Ans)) / @Ans)
set @Miles = CEILING(@Miles)

return @Miles
```

Edit: By the way, there's a good open source control that you can use in ASP.net on Codeplex.

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response, can i check with u on the formula?

what does @DegToRad, @lat1 2 and @Long1 2 stands for? Assuming u have two points to check whether they are close to each other, why do you need DegToRad for? Thankss

Comment: Jonathan, @DegToRad is a constant which is defined at the beginning of the function as 57.29577951, @lat1 and @long1 are variables sent to the function which represent the latitude and longitude of the first point. @lat2 and @long2 are the latitude and longitude of the second point. Also, I added a link to an open source Google Maps control you may want to check out.

Comment: oh ok, i get the lat and long already.. but what is the purpose of constant, is it to check whether point 1 and point 2 is within the range of the constant value as defined? Thanks

Comment: The constant is just needed to do the math required to calculate the distance between the two points. The formula returns the distance between point #1 and point #2 in miles. You can use the to determine if it close enough for your purposes.